# Text Summariser NLP api for JAVA [ Summarising Big Text into small summary ]

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

Can we summarise the website content in 5 lines ? using NLP library in JAVA?

I see apache libraries for open nlp but none of them talks about summarisation or conclusion of the big text in 5 lines or some set of lines ?

I see more libraries as follow but will they provide text summarisation into small summary ?

1|Apache OpenNLP

2| Apache UIMA

3| GATE Embedded

4| LingPipe

5| MALLET

6| NLP4J

7| Stanford CoreNLP

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping something like Huggingface Transformers into a library you can use from Java, but I can't help with that directly, since I am not a Java developer, but if you also consider web APIs, there are few, like Neuralfinity's Magic-Summary which provides a GraphQL endpoint to pass your text to and returns a summary.